# Jquery Else Statement not working

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

My problem is that the **else** section here doesn't seem to work.
I already surfed the web for a solution and even though there are very many questions exactly like mine, the answer always seems to be different.

This is the button I click on

```
<input type="submit" value="4">
```

I also have a button like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="b1" value="Back">
```

My Aim is to find out if the button with an ID was clicked or not.

---

```
var specify = "";
var prevpos = 0;

$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    specify = $(this).attr('value');

    if($(this).attr('id').substring(0,1) == "b")
    {
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevpos}, 777);
       $(".right").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
       $(".left").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
       // more stuff here                           
    }   
    else
    {
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevpos}, 777);  
       // more stuff here
    }
});
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it's not hitting `else` then it must be going into the original `if`. The else can't break.

Comment: see wat ur doing is ur finding the id attribute and then directly accessing its value thru substring. wat if the $(this).attr('id') returns null??its null for the first run, hence the code nvr executes after the if condition. u shd place a null chek

Comment: This is a bad approach I think. Add an id to the other button as well and create another subroutine function to abstract the logic needed for both. Then add the same click callback for both and pass in $(this) as an argument to said subroutine. (this is scalable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is because when you click the button without an `id` you are calling `substr()` on a null, which will cause errors.

Try this instead:

```
var specify = "";

$('button').click(function () {
    specify = $(this).attr('value');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // check there is an id, and if so see if it begins with 'b'
    if (id && id.substring(0, 1) == "b") {
        alert("You clicked the button WITH an id");
    } 
    else {
        alert("You clicked the button WITHOUT an id");
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HwLWP/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var specify = "";
var prevpos = 0;

$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    specify = $(this).attr('value');

    if($(this).attr('id') && $(this).attr('id').substring(0,1) == "b")
    {
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevpos}, 777);
       $(".right").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
       $(".left").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
       // more stuff here                           
    }   
    else
    {
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevpos}, 777);  
       // more stuff here
    }
});
```

You probably need to check whether the element has the id attribute at all before checking on its value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement some time ago and here's my solution:

```
var specify = "";
var prevpos = 0;

$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){ //Note the addition of 'e'
    var id = e.target.id; // If the element has no ID you should get an empty string here

    specify = $(this).attr('value');

    if( id.match(/^b/) ) { // This is a regular expression, if the ID starts with 'b' then it matches
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevpos}, 777);
       $(".right").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200);
       $(".left").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 200);
       // more stuff here                           

    } else {
       $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevpos}, 777);  
       // more stuff here
    }
});
```